# Best Way to Recover from Running Empty Migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rake

I created a migration a while ago that I must have forgotten to populate or something.  I just went to recreate it and got the following:

```
Another migration is already named add_user_id_to_comments:
foo/db/migrate/20121103004535_add_user_id_to_comments.rb
```

I've run `rake db:migrate' a bunch of times since and have a handfull of new migrations...

What's the best way out of this mess?

Comment: rename it to **20121103004535_add_user_id_to_comments_fix_ouch_from_the_past.rb**, open up the file and modify the class name appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the old one is completely blank, just delete it. Its absence will not adversely affect anything. If you want to remove all traces, you'll also want to remove 20121103004535 from your `schema_migrations` table, but it is not required....

Comment: This is what I was hoping for.. I got rid of it and everything seems fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about just renaming your current migration?

```
add_user_id_to_comments_1.rb
```